# Problems installing Scala (a GTK/X11) application on macOS 10.14.6 or macOS 10.11.3

Tags: x11

- macOS 10.14.6 or 10.11.3
- XQuartz 2.7.11 (X11)
- gtk2 2.24.31

I am trying to install Scala (not the programming language, but a music scale utility) and I have been following the instructions at http://www.huygens-fokker.org/scala/downloads.html#Mac

The pre-reqs seem to install okay, but when I try to run the Scala software, it gives me the following error...

[image: Scala error]

Ideally, I would like to remove GTK+ completely from my system and reinstall from scratch, but I don't know how to do this, and I'm not sure it would help in any case.

Does anyone know how I can get this application to run?

Comment: I would ask the author as the instructions are for Long dead OSes. I would also try to launch xterm first to see that x11 works  and then the app

Comment: I gave up on getting that app to work, and, instead, used this web-based solution https://sevish.com/scaleworkshop/. It's much more simple and intuitive, and, critically, it works 